# ng-include in meanjs stack

Tags: angularjs, meanjs

I have problems by using ng-include in angular.js if I try to include more than one file, like the below html.
It works fine with one, but not with two files. And it works fine with both files. 
Also it ignores html following ng-include.

**I get this error:**

```
>>TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null
>>    at http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:3022:13
>>    at forEach (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:325:18)
>>    at forEach.after (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:3021:5)
>>    at Object.JQLite.(anonymous function) [as after] >>>>(http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:3110:17)
>>    at Object.$AnimateProvider.$get.enter (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:4230:17)
>>    at Object.angular.module.directive.factory.config.$provide.decorator.enter (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.js:596:21)
>>    at http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:20024:26
>>    at publicLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:6041:29)
>>    at $get.boundTranscludeFn (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:6166:21)
>>    at controllersBoundTransclude (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:6773:18)
```

Comment: Could you add your markup?

Comment: You need to show your HTML and some JS which runs as well, else it's next to impossible to help you. What we can see is you're running insertBefore on a DOM object which doesn't exist after an http call.

Comment: Here ise my view html

<section data-ng-controller="MarkersController" data-ng-init="initEdit()">
<br><br><br>
<div class="inline frame" data-ng-include="'/modules/markers/html/marker-view1.html'"/>
<div class="inline frame" data-ng-include="'/modules/markers/html/marker-view2.html'"/>
<div>Hello world</div>    
</section>



and marker-view1 (and 2 as well)

<div>
 <p>{{marker.markerName}}</p>
</div>

Comment: Now I found some funny things.
It works if I add an end tag like </div> instead of ending the <div> tag with  />

<section data-ng-controller="MarkersController" data-ng-init="initEdit()">
<br><br><br>
<div data-ng-include="'/modules/markers/html/marker-view1.html'"></div>
<div data-ng-include="'/modules/markers/html/marker-view2.html'"></div>
<div>Hello world</div>    
</section>

Thats strange .....

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with self closing tag. `The HTML parser ignores the ending /` Please follow [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1237) for further details.